# Como eu posso fazer essa função recursiva

Tags: python, recursão

Implemente uma função recursiva filtro_recursivo
ela recebe uma lista e um numero e retorna a lista,
tirando todas as vezes que o número aparece

> Por exemplo `filtro_recursivo([0,1,2,1,4],1)` retorna `[0,2,4]`
>   Por exemplo `filtro_recursivo([0,1,2,1,4],4)` retorna `[0,1,2,1]`
>   Por exemplo `filtro_recursivo([0,1,2,1,4],5)` retorna `[0,1,2,1,4]`
>   Por exemplo `filtro_recursivo([],5)` retorna `[]`

O primeiro teste pega o "caso simples": listas com 0 ou 1 elemento
Depois de passar ele, implemente a recursão usando as duas ideias abaixo

- `filtro_recursivo([5, resto],5) = filtro_recursivo(resto);`
- `filtro_recursivo([8, resto],5) = [8]+filtro_recursivo(resto);`

implementei assim só que não passou no teste

```
def filtro_recursivo(lista, numero):
    for i in range(0, len(lista)):
        if lista [i] == numero:
            lista.pop(i)
    return lista
```

Comment: O que é esse identificador `resto`?

Comment: é o resto dar recursão .

Comment: Resto da recursão? Não faz o menor sentido

Comment: Como que você pode  obter o resto de uma operação que ainda não ocorreu?

Comment: Se uma das respostas abaixo resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, escolha a que você mais gostou e marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique a vontade para comentar.

Answer (score 2):

O conceito de uso de recursividade está equivocado.

Ao meu ver nesse exercício a recursividade é pedida para se iterar funcionalmente pelos elementos da lista e descartar o primeiro elemento cada nova iteração. Isso significa que não deve-se fazer o uso de laços de iteração `while` ou `for`.

```
def filtro(lista, numero):     
  if len(lista) == 0: return lista       #Se a lista for vazia a retorna terminando o ciclo de iterações
  # Se lista[0] = numero retorna o resultado da filtragem de lista[1] até o final da lista
  #Senão insere lista[0] o resultado da filtragem de lista[1] até o final da lista
  return filtro(lista[1:], numero) if lista[0] == numero else [lista[0]] + filtro(lista[1:], numero)
```

Teste no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@RonaldoVasques/FiltragemRecusiva)

O mesmo código só que de maneira mais legível

```
def filtro(lista, numero):    
    
  if len(lista) == 0: return lista       #Se a lista for vazia a retorna terminando o ciclo de iterações      
  resultado = filtro(lista[1:], numero)  #Faz a filtragem recursiva da lista menos o primeiro elemento
  #Se lista[0] != numero... 
  if lista[0] != numero:
     resultado.insert(0, [lista[0]]);    #...insere no resultado o primeiro elemento da lista
  return resultado
```

Comment: boa explicação brigado Augusto

Answer (score 1):

O que você deve fazer é verificar dentro da função se há o valor ou não na lista. Se houver um valor, a função retorna o resultado da mesma função passando os mesmos parâmetros.

Caso o valor não exista mais na lista, a função retornará a lista sem modificação. Você também pode utilizar o método `copy()` para que a lista original não seja afetada.

```
def filtro(lista, value):
    lista = lista.copy()

    if value in lista:
        lista.remove(value)
        return filtro(lista, value)

    return lista

print(filtro([1, 0, 2, 1, 4, 5, 3, 2, 0], 2))  # [1, 0, 1, 4, 5, 3, 0]
```

Ainda assim, não acho uma boa ideia criar uma função recursiva para isso. Um simples laço de repetição `while` já resolve este problema:

```
def filtro(lista, value):
    lista = lista.copy()

    while value in lista:
        lista.remove(value)

    return lista
```